# Estoy haciendo un sistema para agregar usuarios a una pagina web con ASP.net y MySql, y tengo este error CS7036

Tags: mysql, asp.net, login, registro

He intentado con todo lo que sabía, y sigue apareciendo este error: "No se ha dado ningún argumento que corresponda al parámetro formal requerido 'id_role' de 'conexiones.AgregarUsuario(string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string)"
Esto es lo que tengo

```
 public class conexiones
    {
        //********************************************************************************      
        public static int UsuariosRepetidos(string username, string encriptada, string name, string Userbirthday, string User_Gender, string email, string Address, string Cellphone, string id_role)
        {
            int valor = 0;
            MySqlConnection conexion = datos.ObtenerConexion();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT User_ID FROM users_info WHERE sername='" + username + "'", conexion);
            valor = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            if (valor != 0)
            {
             //no es necasario validar aqui ya que en el formulario Registro tengo alertas si valor = 0
            }
            else
            {
                conexiones.AgregarUsuario(name, username, Userbirthday, encriptada, User_Gender, email, Address, Cellphone, id_role);
            }
            conexion.Close();
            return valor;
        }

        //********************************************************************************
        public static int AgregarUsuario(string username, string User_Pass, string seed, string name, string Userbirthday, string User_Gender, string Address, string Email, string Cellphone, string id_role)
        {
            int retorno = 0;
            MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(string.Format("Insert into users_info (Name, username, User_Pass, User_Birthday, User_Gender, Address, Email, Cellphone, id_role) values ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{8}',)", name, username, User_Pass, Userbirthday, User_Gender, Address, Email, Cellphone, id_role), datos.ObtenerConexion());
            retorno = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return retorno;
        }

    }
```

Ayuda porfavor :(, el error me aparece en el primer `Conexiones.AgregaUsuario`

Comment: ¿Cómo haces la llamada a ese método? Creo que el valor que le pasas, no corresponde al tipo esperado (string) y si no, el valor que espera el insert para id_role ¿seguro que debe ser un insert? lo mas común es que sea de tipo entero.

Comment: creo que el problema puede estar aca:
('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{8}',)
Terminas con una "," pero no hay variable. deberias de sacar esa "," y dejarlo asi : ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}') y Repetis 2 veces {8} ?

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos inconsistencias en la consulta:

- Hay una coma sobrante al final de *values (... `,`)
- Son solo 9 campos, pero en VALUES hay 10 elementos, probablemente porque se agregó 2 veces el parametro `'{8}'`

  MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(string.Format("Insert into users_info (Name, username, User_Pass, User_Birthday, User_Gender, Address, Email, Cellphone, id_role) values ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}')", name, username, User_Pass, Userbirthday, User_Gender, Address, Email, Cellphone, id_role), datos.ObtenerConexion());

Otro problema no visible pueden ser que alguno de los valores contenga el caracter `'` y esten rompiendo la sintaxis de la consulta. En este caso conviene declarar los parametros de la query usando las funciones de API:

```
MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand("Insert into users_info (Name, username, User_Pass, User_Birthday, User_Gender, Address, Email, Cellphone, id_role) values (@Name, @username, @User_Pass, @User_Birthday, @User_Gender, @Address, @Email, @Cellphone, @id_role)";
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);
// resto de los parametros con @ asociados a las variables locales
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_role", id_role);
```

Comment: ¡Gracias a todos! al final el error se debía a que ´string seed´ era una variable que ya no usaba, y que no había eliminado de la query, por lo que esa era la inconsistencia, aunque también los consejos de @F.Igor fueron de gran ayuda